# Шаблонизатор и нагрузка на сервер

Tags: php

Пишу свою cms под новостной портал, будет очень большой поток пользователей. Как сильно влияет использование шаблонизатора на нагрузку сервера?

Comment: Очевидно, зависит от конкретного шаблонизатора

Comment: @andreymal шаблонизатор самый простой самописный, простая замена с помощью `str_replace()`

Comment: Тогда вам и надо просто взять и измерить его производительность :)

Comment: @andreymal подскажите как?

Comment: и почему же не воспользоваться известными шаблонизаторами, которые шаблон компилируют единоразово и в т.ч. имеют функции кеширования?

Comment: @teran [NIH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_invented_here)?